# How to refer to data parameter of getJSON in json?

Tags: php, json

I have a getJSON function on my main html page. id is an integer that I'm trying to pass to the php (json encoded) to use as a key in my faqs array below. I was wondering how to refer to the string (1,2 or 3) passed into the php to use it.

**getJSON code:**

```
$.getJSON("faqs.php", id, function(data){
//$.getJSON("faqs.php?topic=field", function(data) {
    if(data == "") {
        $("<div>", {class: "list-group-item", text: "Please add FAQs."}).appendTo($("#topic-container"));
    }
    $.each(data, function(faqId, faq){
        $("<div>", {id: "faq" + faqId, class: "list-group-item", text: faq}).appendTo($("#topic-container"));
    });
});
```

**faqs.php**

```
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');

{"faqs":
    {"1":[
        {
        "question": "What is the best musical instrument in the world?",
        "answer": "The English concertina"
        },
        {
        "question": "How many double bass players does it take to change a light bulb?",
        "answer": "None, the piano player can do that with his left hand."
        }
        ],
      "2":[
        {
        "question": "Why do programmers confuse halloween and christmas?",
        "answer": "Because Oct 31 = Dec 25."
        }
        ],
     "3":[
        {
        "question": "Should I eat more pizza?",
        "answer": "Yes. Always."
        }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: In case you didn't notice, I've posted an answer for your question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have set the `id` variable correctly in `json format` like: `var id = {id: 5};`

And based on the json structure you have posted, you have one node `faqs`. So first you have to get it like this: `var faqs = data.faqs;` then loop through this object.

You also have at lease 1 pair of question and answer in each node so it's better to create two different `<div>` for them and then append them to another `<div>` for each question. And I noticed that you have 2 pairs of Q and A in you first FAQ, So you have to have an internal loop to loop through list of Q and A of each FAQ which I'm doing in this line: `for(iCnt = 0; iCnt < faq.length; iCnt++){`

The final code will look like this:

```
var id = {id: 5}; // Just in case you need a correct format

$.getJSON("faqs.php", id, function(data){
    var faqs = data.faqs;
    $.each(faqs, function(faqId, faq){
        $('<div/>')
            .attr('id', 'faq'+faqId)
            .addClass("list-group-item")
            .appendTo($("#topic-container"));

        for(iCnt = 0; iCnt < faq.length; iCnt++){
            var q = $('<div/>')
                .attr('id', 'q-'+faqId+'-'+iCnt)
                .text(faq[iCnt].question)
                .appendTo('#faq'+faqId); // div for each question

            var a = $('<div/>')
                .attr('id', 'a-'+faqId+'-'+iCnt)
                .text(faq[iCnt].answer)
                .appendTo('#faq'+faqId); // div for each answer
        }
    });
});
```